# Powershell: Recursively Replace String in Select Sub-files of a Directory

Tags: powershell, file-io, windows-xp

I'm using Powershell on Windows XP and am trying to write a command that will:

```
1. read all .bat,.cfg, and .config files
2. replace a string (it's actually the path...these files were all moved)
3. overwrite the existing files with the new one (same name, same location, etc.)
```

I am not a Powershell user, but I have managed to piecemeal the following together:

```
gci -r -include "*.bat","*.config","*.cfg" 
    | gc 
    | foreach { $_ -replace "D:","C:\path" } 
    | sc ??.FullName
```

I'm fairly certain that I've taken care of #1 and #2, but am having trouble figuring out #3 (passing the filename to variable that can be referenced in sc). Any thoughts? Also, let me know if you need any additional information.

**EDIT:**

I managed to work out an answer (see below), but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try:

```
gci -r -include "*.bat","*.config","*.cfg" |
 foreach-object { $a = $_.fullname; ( get-content $a ) |
 foreach-object { $_ -replace "D:","C:\path" }  | 
set-content $a }
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, though you missed a bracket after "C:\path".

Comment: Okay, this is a good fix, but the indenting here is really really difficult to read. If you leave a brace open, please indent!

Comment: When I tried this, a BOM marker was added to the modified files.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the above code on ALL FILES use this code, note the top line:

```
gci -r *.* |
foreach-object { $a = $_.fullname; ( get-content $a ) |
foreach-object { $_ -replace "master81","master" }  | 
set-content $a }
```

if you leave out `*.*` you may get errors because you are trying to edit folders.

*[Get-Content], UnauthorizedAccessException*

Answer (score 0):

I recognized that I needed an extra variable. One way to do this is by integrating a for-loop into the outer portion of the command. I used:

```
foreach ($f in gci -r -include "*.bat") 
    { (gc $f.fullname) |
       foreach { $_ -replace "D:","C:\path" }  |
       sc $f.fullname 
    }
```