# Powershell: Invalid regular expression

Tags: powershell, file-io, windows-xp

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368786/powershell-recursively-replace-string-in-select-sub-files-of-a-directory) posting, I managed to replace a string in a directory's subfiles with Powershell on Windows XP.

```
foreach ($f in gci -r -include "*.bat") 
    { (gc $f.fullname) |
       foreach { $_ -replace "D:","C:\path" }  |
       sc $f.fullname 
    }
```

Unfortunately, a few exceptional cases required a "C:\\" rather than a "C:\".

I attempted to use the following command to fix this problem (replacing "C:\path\\" with "C:\\path\\"), but it fails:

```
foreach ($f in gci -r -include "*.bat") 
    { (gc $f.fullname) |
       foreach { $_ -replace "C\path\\","C:\\path\\" }  |
       sc $f.fullname 
    }
```

The error is:

```
Invalid regular expression pattern: C:\path\\
```

I attempted several variants in an effort to circumvent the problem, but all produce the same error (replacing line #3 above):

```
foreach { $_ -replace "C:\path\\\\","C:\\path\\" } |
foreach { $_ -replace 'C:\path\\',"C:\\path\\" } |
foreach { $_ -replace "`C:\path\\","C:\\path\\" } |
foreach { $_ -replace 'C:\path\\\\',"C:\\path\\" } |
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you missing the ':' for some reason in you code?

Comment: @Christian: No, sorry, just a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For repalcing replacing "C:\path\" with "C:\\path\\"

use

```
$_ -replace "c:\\path\\\\","c:\\path\\"
```

The Match pattern is regex and '\' needs to be escaped with an '\'.
The replace string is just a string, no needs escape characters

Comment: Of course...I was a little too focused on the wrong set of backslashes. Thanks again!

Comment: For these types of cases where literal text needs to be found, I usually escape the search parameter using `$escapedSearch = [regex]::Escape('C:\path\')` . The use `$escapedSearch` with `-replace`. This is definitely helpful when the literal text is a variable and could be anything.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can [use the Replace() method of the string class](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/powershell/string-replacement/):

> ```
> PS> $folder = "C:\FolderName\NextFolder\ThirdFolder"
> PS> $newfolder = $folder.Replace("C:\FolderName\", "D:\")
> PS> $newfolder
> D:\NextFolder\ThirdFolder
> ```

Comment: You sir has saved my life! This is so much better when dealing with situations where path is involved and regex can't stand special chars like backslashes!

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on what CB said, when replacing "\" in a string, you have to escape them in the "find" part of the string.  The easiest way to do this is as follows

```
$escapedPath = $path -replace "\\","\\"
```

or to clarify:

```
$escapedPath = $path -replace [RegEx]"\\",[String]"\\"
```

Because the first parameter in -replace is a RegEx, it treats "\" differently then the second half which is a String datatype.